# How to use promise value outside of it in typescript?

Tags: typescript, asynchronous, promise

I am doing something like this in a typescript library/npm package

```
async function fetchSomeData() {}

function returnData(): string {
    let result!: undefined;
    fetchSomeData.then((value) => result = value);
    return result;
}
```

The `returnData()` always return undefined. When I use `console.log()` inside `.then()` I am able to see the data but outside `.then()` when I use `result`, it is undefined. I want the output of the `returnData()` to be string as it is being used somewhere else which requires a string output.

Comment: The line:

`fetchSomeData.then((value) => result = value)`

is asynchronous. So, the line:

`return result;`

doesn't wait and it executes before 

`result = value`

You can utilize either async/await or the .then syntax. One fix:

function fetchSomeData() {
    return new Promise(resolve => resolve('data'));/*promise returning a string*/
}

async function returnData() {
    fetchSomeData().then(value => {
        console.log(value);/*Here it's a string; the promise was resolved. You can work here or call another function to process the value*/
    });
}
returnData();

Comment: I tried it but then I get an error saying `Type Promise<String> is not assignable to Type String` as the returnData function is being used at multiple places which needs string. The returnData function is more like a utility function in my code that is being used to provide values to other functions